# jqGrid problem, expecting jQuery.jgrid but $.jgrid exists instead

Tags: java, javascript, jqgrid, jira

I'm using jqGrid for a JIRA plugin and have included the jquery and jqgrid libraries as web resources.

I've set up a column in jqGrid as required and when I try to submit the form with the respective column empty I get an error in firebug: jQuery.jgrid is undefined

jQuery.jgrid is null but $.jgrid has the correct data.

Does anyone know how I can set up jqgrid so that it points to the $.jgrid without having to change all the source code? or any other way round this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: @SLaks I have the following js files included: jquery-1.3.2.min.js,jquery-1.7.2.custom.min.js, grid.locale-en.js, jquery.jqGrid.min.js using jqGrid version 3.6.4

Comment: since I'm developing a jira plugin maybe JIRA has a version of jQuery loaded which is conflicting??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really weird. Maybe this will work:

```
jQuery.fn.jgrid = $.jqgrid;
```

You should try that, but I'm really not shure if it will work.

Comment: i'm trying to add jQuery.fn.jgrid = $.jgrid; to the end of the $(document).ready(function() function in my velocity template but I can't seem to escape the $ sign probably. as it is the $ sign disappears even with a backslash in front of it

Comment: I've done a quick hack and added a field to my action class which would return the string $.jgrid and have set jQuery.jgrid = $action.jQueryHack;